# How to save image

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to save image with userdefaults and use it in another view with this code but it shows an error .

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(img , forKey : "simg")
```

please help me

Comment: First of all don't misuse `UserDefaults` as temporary data storage between view (controllers), second of all if you get an error the type of `img` is not property list compliant.

Comment: The better is to save the image to documents then save the path to the image in `UserDefaults`, which will be an easy task.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed how can i do that !?

Comment: @vadian how can i change type of image !?

Comment: That depends on the type of `img`

Comment: Check the last section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21810380/4763963).

Comment: @vadian how can i informed frim my image type !?

Comment: As the developer you are supposed to know the static type of `img`

Comment: @MJP - Are you trying to "save" the image so you can re-load and re-use it the next time the user runs the app? Or are you just trying to select an image in one place in your app, and then show it in another place?

Comment: @DonMag the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. You have multiple places to save it to, the user's Documents folder is usually best:

```
func cacheImageAsPNG(image: UIImage, localID: String) {
    let userDocumentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        let filename = userDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(localID).png")

        if  FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: filename.path, contents: imageData, attributes: nil) {
            print("wrote file:\n\(filename.path)")
        } else {
            print("couldn't write the file:\n\(filename.path)")
        }
    }
}
```

if you want it erased by the system during times of peak memory usage, the cache directory is a better place:

```
 let cachesPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last!
```

Edit: Retrieving the Image

```
func cachedImage(localID: String) -> UIImage? {
    let userDocumentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
    let cachePath = userDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(localID).png")

    return UIImage(named: cachePath.path)
}
```

Comment: You should probably show how to read the image in from the saved file as well.

Comment: I agree. Done. I was waiting to see how saving worked out so I could adjust my answer. But it's best to leave the answer complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save a UIImage directly to `NSUserDefaults`.  You could save it as `NSData`, but it really is not advisable.  `NSUserDefaults` is meant to store small bits of information in key value pairs.  If you start throwing images in there, you could overload the space reserved for it. The contents of the `NSUserDefaults` is written to a plist. I believe any time you access the user defaults, it reads the whole file. If you put large images in there, it will cause a lot of unnecessary I/O.

If you still decide to do it (not recommended), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29402491/3708242) is a good post on getting an `NSData` object from the image.

Comment: I take image in view and i want to show that image in another view

Comment: If you are just looking to save  an image to be used on another view, I would do as @Mozahler suggests in his answer and save it to the user's Documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, don't save images to user defaults. It's only intended for small bits of data.

If all you want to do is to pass an image in another view controller, and you don't care about making the image persist if the user quits and re-launches the app, just pass the image in `prepareForSegue`.